# php create array out of string one per line

Tags: php, regex, arrays

i got a

```
$str ="sometxt<br>another<br>moretext<br>evenmoretext<br>";
```

i'm trying to output the string in one array per line.

kinda like this..

```
[0] => Array
        (['stuff'] => sometext
        )
[1] => Array
        (['stuff'] => another
        )
[2] => Array
        (['stuff'] => moretext
        )
[3] => Array
        (['stuff'] => evenmoretext
        )
```

i'm using regex to get the str..
if u need more clarification..i will do. thanks in advance

Comment: sorry i don't get what you want to do? do you want to split the string into an array?

Comment: doesnt really make any sense. why are you putting "stuff" in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $str ="sometxt<br>another<br>moretext<br>evenmoretext<br>";
    $r = array("stuff" => explode("<br>", $str));
    print_r($r);
?>

Array
(
    [stuff] => Array
        (
            [0] => sometxt
            [1] => another
            [2] => moretext
            [3] => evenmoretext
            [4] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: I think that the endgame is not just the output, and beside that, you'd need to add a <pre> tag before and after the print_r to get the response you placed ;) Nice one anyways!

Comment: I use this:
Header('Content-Type:text/Plain')

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$arr = explode("<br>", $str);

$resp = array();
foreach ( $arr as $val ){
  $resp[] = array("stuff" => $val);
}
```

I think this code would solve your dilemma. Tell me if you need any clarification.